# Meaning of superscript for a vector in R

Tags: r

Say you have a vector X

then we make a qqplot using `qqnorm(X)`

But then we need to make qqplots of log X, X^.1,X^.2....

I have down `qqnorm(log(X))` for the first one

However, what do those superscripts of .1,.2 want me to do

I don't think its just `qqnorm(log(X^.1))` and so on since they look the exact same

Comment: `^` is an exponent operator, nothing special about it. `X^0.1` is to raise each value of the vector `X` to the power of `0.1`; R does that efficiently in a vectorized operation. From there, to `log` and `qqnorm` it doesn't matter, it's just another vector of numbers (that happens to be the same length).

Comment: the problem though is that when graphed, they all look the same

Comment: They are going to look similar, but look closely. The vertical `Sample Quantiles` axis should change its scale, but the shape of the curve might not. Could you post the plots produced and maybe share how you expect them to be different?

Comment: Yes, but im not sure how to post plots on here, and you are right, the vertical axis is changing, just not the curve shape. However, how will i know which one indicates normality the most if all the curves are the same shape? Because the most normal qqplot is when y=x,